# Correct way of converting string to date when a string is in given format?

Tags: angular, date

I have a string with below date format

```js
const strDate = '10-23-2022';
```

to convert this to date I was using below line of code

```js
new Date(strDate);
```

this is all working fine in Chrome but the issue is in mozilla firefox I am getting invalid date error. So what is the correct way of converting string to date that works across all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try one of them

1. Pipe

```
getFormatedDate(date: Date, format: string) {
    const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US'); // culture of your date
    return datePipe.transform(date, format);
}
```

2. moment.js

```
    let parsedDate = moment(dateStr,"MM-DD-YYYY");
    let outputDate = parsedDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

3. Simple Split

```
const str = '10-23-2022';

const [month, day, year] = str.split('-');

console.log(month); // ️ "10"
console.log(day); // ️ "23"
console.log(year); // ️ "2022"

const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: Great answer, although I would advice not to use momentjs anymore. It’s EOL.